# Spilt hindi paragraph by | in java

Tags: java, string, split, hindi

I want to split a Hindi paragraph into sentences. Each sentence is separated by '|' . 
I tried the following code :

```
String[] translated_values=text.split("|");
```

Sample text :

```
मनोवैज्ञानिक परीक्षण। खुफिया भागफल खुफिया की उम्र से संबंधित उपाय के लिए (बुद्धि) टेस्ट। चिकित्सा देखभाल
```

but it doesn't work. This works when splitting with other symbols like , etc . please help me.

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: It's probably not the same character you are using in your `split()`. Copy-paste for best results

Comment: hi kaykay. I tried that. but still the same issue

Answer (score 2):

`|` is  a special char in regex (*alternation operator*) which will do the regex logical OR operation. You need to escape `|` in-order to match a literal pipe symbol.

```
String[] values = text.split("\\|");
```

Comment: or `String[] values = text.split("[|]");`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply., This is not working. I tried both the solutions.

Comment: Think `|` in your input is not actually a pipe symbol. Just directly copy that symbol and put it on your split function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape it:

Try:

```
String[] translated_values=text.split("\\|");
```

Comment: Then try:
String[] value_split = rat_values.split(Pattern.quote("|")); @julikaZen

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the character | directly, use the unicode value of it.
This should work

```
String[] translated_values=text.split("\u0964");
```